# Cannot access article, get 1146 error.

Tags: articles

I cannot access any articles on my Joomla, all i get is this error:

> 1146 Table 'trasman.trasman_jreviews_categories' doesn't exist
>   SQL=SELECT dirid FROM trasman_jreviews_categories WHERE id = 83 The
>   Page you are looking for doesn't exist or an other error occurred.
>
> Go back, or head over to the home page to choose a new direction.

Please see the http://www.trasman.mu/test link for more info.

i googled a lot for the error, but got mostly obscure answers. Please advise.

Comment: Are you using Joomla's built-in Article Manager for your articles? Cause the table you have defined in your question does not belong to Joomla by default

Comment: How do i check that ?

Comment: Well simple, when you type the content for your articles, are you using Joomla's Article Manager which you access via the top menu in the backend, or are you using a different extension?

Comment: From the menu content, i can clearly see Article manager and i use that to edit the existing articles. I can edit the articles fine but i just cannot view them...

Comment: Hmm, well the database table you have defined in your question does not belong to Joomla's Article Manager. It belongs to a 3rd party extension and having looked around, it might be [this one](http://www.reviewsforjoomla.com/), but not too sure. Nevertheless, you should contact the developer of this extension.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to revert it back ? i did some search and found that Open Graph - JReviews  was there. I disabled the plugin but i still get the same error.

Comment: I don't know how JReviews work as I have never used it before. You will need to disable every reference to it. It's possible that there are multiple plugins for it and possibly a component. Disable all of them.

Comment: Ok its solved, post your answer below and i will mark it as read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database table defined has no association with Joomla's Article Manager. It belong to a 3rd party extensions (JReviews), which I believe to be this one:

http://www.reviewsforjoomla.com/

It appears the table for this extension is missing, therefore you can either try reinstalling the extensions, or disable it. It would also be worth contacting the developer if you have tried reinstalling it and the issue still occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i disabled the extension and now i can view my articles without any issues.